# Centos 8 kvm bridged guest (OS type hvm) can only communicate with host

Tags: centos, kvm, vyos

A little stumped with my kvm host, especially since I setup the exact same situation on a different host and it works well.
I have a proxmox Centos 8 vm that I've had to setup as a kvm host, with a single interface and multiple network bridges for kvm guests.
So the vms have to be type hvm (nested hypervisor).

I setup a kvm guest (vyos vm) on a bridged interface, expecting it to be able to communicate with the host network, but unless I setup firewalld masquerading, the guest cant communicate with the host's gateway and network, only with the host itself, host + guest can ping each other.

Host sysctl.conf is normal:

```
    net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1
    net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
    net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
    net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
```

Firewalld as well:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br0 br1 ens18
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

The nested vm:

```
virsh dominfo <domname>
Id:             1
Name:           <domname>
UUID:           6ce2fae5-2e57-428b-ad29-49a067866161
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         4
```

I havent noticed anything else.
Please help, anyone!

Comment: Give some clarifications: If I get it correct, you have a Proxmox host. A Centos8 VM runs on Proxmox host. And KVM is enabled on the VM? So, nested hypervisor? Another confusing part, type HVM is used on Xen hypervisors, not KVM ones.

Comment: I have access to a CentOS 8 vm running on a proxmox host. Yes nested hypervisor on the CentOS 8 vm. From `virsh dominfo <domain>:` : ` virsh dominfo edge2
Id:             1
Name:           edge2
UUID:           6ce2fae5-2e57-428b-ad29-49a067866161
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         4`